# Django Shell Plus Clear History

Tags: django, django-shell

Is there a command to clear the history of Django's Shell Plus?

I did not find any hints in the documentation or by typing `?`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing the ipython history (`~/.ipython/profile_default/history.sqlite`) did the job.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the `readline` python package to clear history of Django Shell:

```
import readline
readline.clear_history()
```